# What is the name of the Griffin that was given to Kes in Lord of the Changing Winds?

Tags: names, lord-of-the-changing-winds

I want to know the name that was given to the character Kes in *Lord of the Changing Winds* by Rachel Neumier. I can't seem to find it online anywhere and don't have access to the book right now. I recall it translating to "fire kitten" in the human tongue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the relevant passage

> *Kereskiita*—said the young brown griffin.
>   “My name is Kes!” Kes said, with unusual urgency, somehow doubting, in the back of her mind, that this was still true.
>   *Yes*, said Opailikiita. *But that is too little to call you. You should have more to your name. Kairaithin called you* kereskiita. *Shall I?*
>   **“Well, but… *kereskiita?* What is that?”
>
>   It would be… “fire kitten,” perhaps, Opailikiita said after a moment. And, with unexpected delicacy, Do you mind?**
>   Kes supposed she didn’t actually *mind*. She asked, “Opailikiita? That’s *kiita*, too.”
>   Glittering flashes of amusement flickered all around the borders of Kes’s mind. *Yes. Opailikiita Sehanaka Kiistaike,* said the young griffin. *Opailikiita is my familiar name. It is… “little spark”? Something close to that. Kairaithin calls me by that name. I am his* kiinukaile. *It would be… “student,” I think. If you wish, you may call me Opailikiita. As you are also Kairaithin’s student.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Lord of the Changing Winds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7069161-lord-of-the-changing-winds)</sup></sub>